# Не получается прикрепить сертификат ssl nginx

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, ssl

www.startcomca.com получил тут сертификат.
У меня nginx.
Вот мой конфиг

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ***;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nginx/***/123.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/***/123.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers  "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH !RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    index   index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        root /usr/html/***;
    } 
}
```

где 123.key это ключ который я получил в результате startcomtool утилиты
а   123.crt то что скачал с сайта в архиве в папке nginxServer
Что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: А что не так? Вы бы описали проблему. Пока что могу предположить, что Хром считает сертификат недействительным. Выкиньте этот start com: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/325300/ и используйте let's encrypt

Comment: Во-первых, почему вы решили, что сделали что-то неправильно? Во-вторых, использовать startcomtool было точно неправильным решением, есть вышеупомянутый let's encrypt

Comment: Во-первых, где доказательства, что неправильно. `nginx -t` в студию, он вам живо на серт ругнётся, если что не так. Во-вторых, зачем нужно использовать startcomtool (давно слез когда их трёхлетние серты стали невалидными), когда есть дваждывышеупомянутый letsencrypt?

Comment: Ну правда, к чему проблемы с постоянно отзывающимися сертификатами, когда есть LE (ставится в один клик, без смс, и конфиг nginx настроит за вас).